# How can we find the minimum cost of redistributing gold.

Tags: optimization, algorithms, dynamic-programming

problem statement: We are given `n` gold mines having `A[i]` amount of gold at `i`th gold mine where `1<=i<=n`. All gold mines are located on a straight line , the location of each mine is given by `B[i]` where `1<=i<=n`. Now we want to consolidate all gold into exactly `k` mines ( by moving gold from remaining `n-k` mines to nearby mines). The cost of moving `amt` amount of gold from mine `i` to mine `j` is distance between them times the amount of gold moved, i.e, `|B[i]-B[j]|*amt` where `0<=amt<A[i]`. We can choose any `k` final gold mine locations where we can consolidate gold from other mines. ( However those `k` final locations must be among original gold mine locations. For example if `n = 2, A = (2, 4), B = (0, 4) and k = 1`, then we will choose final gold locations as `(4)`. cost of moving gold from location 0 to 4 is `4*2 = 8` . If we choose final locations as `(0)`, the cost would be `4*4 = 16`.) Please help me devising an efficient algorithm to compute the minimum cost . Thanks in advance.

Constraints :  `1<=n<=5000`,
`1<=k<=n`,
`A[i]` is non negative.